# CKEditor display on top of all the content flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have found the lot and got one editor which i use in my project (Flex Web application).

I have used CKEditor from this [link.](http://blog.aboutme.be/2009/10/25/ckeditor-running-in-flex-and-air/)

```
<ckeditor:CKEditor id="editor1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <ckeditor:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[

            ]]>
        </ckeditor:htmlText>
</ckeditor:CKEditor>
```

It's working ok in my project. But, there is one issue i am facing.

**Problem:** 
I have one alert message and Custom popup container. I want to display that both on top of the editor. But it hide behind the editor.

I want to display on top of that editor. How can i do this?

Currently look something like:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will be possible because the CKEditor area is drawn over the swf. So you can do, unfortunately, nothing.

Take a look on your html page source code and you'll see what I mean.

**Edit :**

I agree with @fsbmain about using `ExternalInterface`, but to show a JavaScript alert :

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.call('alert', 'some message here !');
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

To hide your CKEditor, you can use a JavaScript function which you can call via `ExternalInterface` :

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function hideCKEditor()
    {
        document.getElementById('ck0').style.display = 'none';
    }       
</script>
```

Then in the ActionScript side :

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
    ExternalInterface.call('hideCKEditor');
}

Alert.show('Your message here !', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I have not only 1 alert message. I have another popup Container. Which should also be display on editor.

Comment: If this is not possible then there is any other good editor available which will work like flex component.

Comment: @ketan But, what about using JavaScript alerts ? Then if you've another question, it's better to post a new question.

Comment: I can not use javascript alert. I have already mention that i am using another popup also. I have added screenshot in my question.

Comment: I use `visible ="false"` to hide the editor than also it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

That editor based on html div (so it's a html element above your swf app), that means that you have only three options to show your popup "over" it:

1. Hide editor when popup is opened - in my mind best option by risks/time ratio

Actually all other methods are dirty cheats and require quite a lot of work with questionable result with a lot of edge cases and potential issues:

2. Show you popup in separate swf above that html, communicate between two swf with `ExternalInterface`
3. Improve on #1 if you really want to show editor in background - make your editor screenshot with JS (try that [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)), send data to flash via `ExternalInterface` and display it in `Bitmap`

Comment: I have not only 1 alert message. I have another popup Container. Which should also be display on editor.

Comment: If this is not possible then there is any other good editor available which will work like flex component.

Comment: I use `visible = "false"` to hide the editor than also it is not working.

Comment: with the same functional as html editor - no, afaik most of editors are quite simple like flex rich text editor and allows you to only edit simple text formatting