# Make CKEditor readonly in flex

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, ckeditor

I have used [CKEditor](http://blog.aboutme.be/2009/10/25/ckeditor-running-in-flex-and-air/) in flex:

```
<ckeditor:CKEditor id="editor1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <ckeditor:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[

            ]]>
        </ckeditor:htmlText>
</ckeditor:CKEditor>
```

It's working fine now. But I need to enable, disable that editor on checkbox. But I can't make disable that editor anyway.

I have found how to **[Hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476662/ckeditor-display-on-top-of-all-the-content-flex)** that editor. But, I want to display that editor on screen. Just need to make is disable.

I have tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function hideCKEditor()
    {
        document.getElementById('ck0').disabled = true;
    }       
</script>
```

But didn't got succeeded.

I want that, user can not Edit the editor text when checkbox is checked.

Comment: You can just cover it by another div to be disabled !

Comment: @akmozo How can i cover in flex with div? Can i scroll inside note editor then after?

Comment: You should do that in the HTML side (HTML, CSS, JS) by creating the div via a JS function called from AS code ...